# How to avoid retrieving previous tweets pulled from Twitter API V2

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am using the Twitter V2 API, is it possible to avoid retrieving tweets that was already retrieved from the Twitter API. For example would it be possible to only retrieve tweets that weren't already pulled from Twitter using the V2 endpoints.

Example:

```
const tweets = await client.v2.userTimeline('12', { exclude: 'replies' });
```

Npm package: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-api-v2)

Comment: Would using the ```since_id``` parameter work?

Comment: Yes, you would use `since_id` or one of the [other parameters](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets) like `start_time`